# sqlalchemy core integrity error

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

I'm working on parsing a file and inserting it into a database, using sqlalchemy core. I had it set up with the orm originally but that doesn't meet the speed requirements for the project.

My database has 2 tables: Objects and Attributes. The Objects table has a primary key of obj_id. The primary key for Attributes is composite: attr_name, attr_class, and obj_id, which is also a foreign key from Objects.

The attributes are stored after parsing the file in a list of dictionaries, like so:

```
[
{ 'obj_id' = obj_id, 'attr_name' = name, 'attr_class' = class, etc...},
{ ETC ETC ETC}]
```

The data is being inserted by first bulk inserting the objects, then the attributes. The object insert works perfectly. When inserting the attributes however, I get an integrity error, saying I tried to insert a duplicate primary key.

Here is my insert code for attributes:

```
self.engine.execute(
            Attributes.__table__.insert(),
                [{'obj_id' : attr['obj_id'],
                  'attr_name' : attr['attr_name'],
                  'attr_class': attr['attr_class'],
                  'attr_type' : attr['attr_type'],
                  'attr_size' : attr['attr_size']} for attr in attrList])
```

While trying to work this error out, I printed the id, name, and class of each attribute in the list to a file to find the duplicate key. Nowhere in the list is there actually an identical primary key, so this leads me to believe it is a problem with the structure of my query.

Can anyone figure this out with the info I've given, or give me somewhere to look for more information? I've already checked the documentation pretty thoroughly and couldn't find anything helpful.

### **Edit:**

I also tried executing each insert statement separately, as suggested by someone on sqlalchemy's google group. The results were the same. The code I used:

```
insert = Attributes.__table__.insert() 
for attr in attrList: 
    stmt = insert.values({'obj_id' : attr['obj_id'], ...}) 
    self.engine.execute(stmt)
```

where ... was the rest of the values.

### **Edit 2:**

The Integrity error is thrown as soon as I try to insert an attribute with the same name/class but a different object id. So for example:

In the format name-class-id:

By iteration 4, I've got:

- Attr1-Class1-0
- Attr2-Class2-0
- Attr3-Class3-0
- Attr4-Class4-0

On the next iteration, I try to insert Attr1-Class1-1, which fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, completely unrelated to the insert code. When storing the data in the list, I was storing an Object as obj_id, which sqlalchemy didn't like. By fixing that I fixed the insertions.

Comment: Just so you're aware, it's not really that "sqlalchemy didn't like" what you were sending - sqlalchemy itself simply passes the values straight along to the underlying database driver. MySQL is notorious for silently converting values when inserting them, rather than signalling an error when given a value of the wrong type. I'd be interested to know what it was inserting in the obj_id column when you were sending a non-integer.

Comment: Very interesting! And good to know moving forward...honestly, I'm new enough to sqlalchemy/MySQL that I wouldn't know how to examine what value is trying to be inserted. It seems as though when converting the Object to an integer, it just becomes 0, because thats what the first ~9 entries had for their obj_id, and what was attempted on the following insert.